# How to repeat all fields key and set the new value in $project stage in aggregate mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema model with so many fields like below example, I want to clone root field in `suggest_foo` to $project stage of aggregation without having to manually rewrite those fields and then set those fields with new value as my logic.

Example:

- schema model:

  ```
  const fooSchema = new Schema({
     suggest_foo: 
       foo1: String,
       foo2: String,
       foo3: String,
       foo4: String,
       foo5: String,
     }
     ...
  })
  ```
- seeds data:

  ```
  {
     suggest_foo: {
       foo1: 'Foo1',
       foo2: 'Foo2',
       foo3: 'Foo3',
       foo4: 'Foo4',
       foo5: 'Foo5',
     }
  }
  ```
- aggregate query code:

  ```
  fooSchema.aggregate([
     ...
     {
       $project: {
          // I want to clone root in suggest_foo (eg: foo1, foo2, foo(n)...) to be here.
       }
     }
  ])
  ```

My output result that I expected look like:

```
  {
     foo1: 'Foo1 maybe you like',
     foo2: 'Foo2 maybe you like',
     foo3: 'Foo3 maybe you like',
     foo4: 'Foo4 maybe you like',
     foo5: 'Foo5 maybe you like',
  }
```

Comment: hello! who can help me?

Comment: We need some more context here. What is the previous step of the aggregation. Why do you need this? This step will be redundant...There is no point in projecting everything... You can just as well skip the projection step...

Comment: @nimrodserok  hello, First of all, I appreciate your enthusiasm. Specifically in my case, I want to replace all root in `suggest_foo` and put it in $project without rewrite manually , example:  `$project: { foo1: 1, foo2: 1, foo3: 1, ...}` and handle value of each field in root with new value to get output as my expected in question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `$replaceRoot` with `$arrayToObject` and `$objectToArray` as this will allow you to manipulate array in a loop:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: {$objectToArray: "$suggest_foo"},
            in: {
              v: {$concat: ["$$this.v", " maybe you like"]},
              k: "$$this.k"
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lRlqTvmGQ9l)

Comment: This is amazing. I can’t thank you enough. 